# Viability of finding variables of a transform chain

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying (and failing) to find the equivalent variables of doing a transform, and applying that to each element. A gif of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

In the gif this is done by premultiplying the local matrix
$ T_{local}(p, a, \alpha, \beta, s) = Translate(p+a) * Rotate(\alpha) * Skew(\beta) * Scale(s) * Translate(-a) $

of the triangles with

$ T_{group}(m, g) = Translate(m) * Scale(g) * Translate(-m) $.

Where $p$, $a$, $α$, $β$, $s$, $g$ and $m$ are known values.
However, what I am trying to achieve is finding values k, l, $\gamma$, $\omega$, & j so that $T_{group}$ wouldn't be needed:

$ T_{group}(m, g) * T_{local}(p, a, \alpha, \beta, s) = T_{local}(k, l, \gamma, \omega, j) $

Putting that up in matrix form it'd be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 g_x & 0 & m_x - g_x * m_x \\
 0 & g_y & m_y - g_y * m_y \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} * 
\begin{pmatrix} 
s_{x}(cos(\alpha) - \beta_ysin(\alpha)) & s_{y}(\beta_xcos(\alpha) - sin(\alpha)) & A \\
s_{x}(sin(\alpha) + \beta_ycos(\alpha)) & s_{y}(\beta_xsin(\alpha) + cos(\alpha)) & B \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
j_{x}(cos(\gamma) - \omega_ysin(\gamma)) & j_{y}(\omega_xcos(\gamma) - sin(\gamma)) & C \\
j_{x}(sin(\gamma) + \omega_ycos(\gamma)) & j_{y}(\omega_xsin(\gamma) + cos(\gamma)) & D \\
0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

where

$A=a_x + p_x  -s_xa_x(cos(\alpha) - \beta_ysin(\alpha)) - s_ya_y(\beta_xcos(\alpha) - sin(\alpha))$

$B=a_y + p_y - s_xa_x(sin(\alpha) + \beta_ycos(\alpha)) - s_ya_y(\beta_xsin(\alpha) + cos(\alpha))$

$C=l_x + k_x  -j_xl_x(cos(\gamma) - \omega_ysin(\gamma)) - j_yl_y(\omega_xcos(\gamma) - sin(\gamma))$

$D=l_y + k_y - j_xl_x(sin(\gamma) + \omega_ycos(\gamma)) - j_yl_y(\omega_xsin(\gamma) + cos(\gamma))$

My initial idea was to put up an equation system, but having 9 unknowns ($k_x$, $k_y$, $l_x$, $l_y$, $\gamma$, $\omega_x$, $\omega_y$, $j_x$ and $j_y$), and 6 equations it doesn't seem solvable, so I'm a bit of a loss of direction on what the next step would be

Does anyone have any pointer on if this is solvable, and any tips for the right direction if that is the case?